# Convert a list of string into json format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

How to convert a list of string

```
 List<string> keys = new List<string>() { "1-12VEXP", "1-124DH9"};
```

To json format same as :

```
[["1-12VEXP"],["1-124DH9"]]
```

in .net.

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json .

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you already tried? Which JSON serializer are you using? (If you're not using anything yet, you should really pick one...)

Comment: That's not JSON, and all you need is JSON.NET.

Comment: @JonSkeet  Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Okay, so presumably you've already tried something - what did you try, and what were the results?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance can you please elaborate how can I get that format

Comment: Serialize it with JSON.NET and replace all the  {s with [s and all the }s with ]s.

Comment: Note what you're asking for - those two are not the same thing. Your C# object is a collection of two strings. Your JSON object is an array which contains two arrays, each of which contains one item. Which do you want?

Comment: Serialization should never involve string manipulation - that's the whole point of it, not having to handle the formatting yourself. So I would not recommend @newStackExchangeInstance's approach (which isn't right anyway).

Comment: @JoeEnos It's fine for what he's asking for.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Serializing a collection gives you a JSON array, which would look like `["a","b"]`. So there wouldn't be any `{` characters in there at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Straight-up serialization won't work, since the items are not equivalent. If you truly want what you're asking for, then you need an array which contains arrays, then serialize that array:

You can do that by first converting your collection, then simple JSON serialization:

```
string[][] newKeys = keys.Select(x => new string[]{x}).ToArray();

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newKeys);
```

Comment: I am using it in WebMethod. But it is showing 'the name ' json object ' does not exist in the current context'. ?? What's the problem here?

Comment: @ShyamDixit Sounds like you've got a separate unrelated problem and should post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

With Newtonsoft.Json:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keys);
```

will give you JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will give you something like [&quot;1-12VEXP&quot;,&quot;1-124DH9&quot;] if for type IList<string>, which likely isn't usable; this would work if he were using type IList of a custom type w/ properties, for example.