# List change to the json format

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I want to change list to json format. How can I do?

```
        var db = new TelephoneBookDataContext();

        List<string> Capitals = (from U in db.Users
                                 where U.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(name.ToLower())
                                 select U.Name).ToList();
        return Capitals;
```

Java script part I cant get as such this code part

```
 $("document").ready(function () {
        $("#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Show.aspx/GetName",
                    data: "{'name':'" + $("#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>").val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
```

Comment: do you mean you want to serialize this list to a json srting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing a list to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110724/serializing-a-list-to-json)

Comment: i dont think its dublicate .. it is list of string type and the reference you  passed is List of objet type .. we cant not Json serialize list of string by using class directly.as done in that code the reference you providing

Comment: I must send list of name in json format

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a list of string into json format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865584/convert-a-list-of-string-into-json-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First Add Name space

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

> Then use JavaScriptSerializer class

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string output = jss.Serialize(ListOfMyObject);
```

> your List is of String Type so you might need this  try below if above
>   donot work.

```
string[][] ArrayCapitals = Capitals.Select(x => new string[]{x}).ToArray();

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ArrayCapitals );
```

Comment: JsonConvert has a error "does not exist in the current context"