# How to merge two lists with different variable types

Tags: java

As the question states I'm wondering what the best way to merge two lists together that have different variable types. I'm unsure if the way I'm going about this problem is the correct way so I'm happy to take all advice regarding this. Basically I'm making a banking application. When the user finishes some transaction data is added to a txt file of the form (Type Date Amount). I want the user to then be able to do some more transactions later and these new transactions added to the end of this txt file.

My Issue is that when I re read the users previous transactions I read them in as a List of strings

```
BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(account.getName()+"Transactions.txt"));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            transactions.add(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
```

however the list of transactions to add to my txt file is of the type Transaction not a String.

```
List<Transaction> transactionsToAdd = new ArrayList<Transaction>()
```

As an example here is some code in the case the user makes a deposit.

```
    case 1:
            amount = scanner.DepositScanner();
            balance = account.Deposit(balance, amount);
            System.out.print("Your new balance is: " + balance);

            String depositFullDate = dateManager.getDateAsString();
            Transaction depositTransaction = new Transaction("Depsoit", amount, depositFullDate);
            transactionsToAdd.add(depositTransaction);

            break;
```

Ideally I want the code to read in the users previous transactions, add their new transactions to the end of the txt file and then save all of these to the same txt file when the user is finished. Is there either a way to read in the users previous transactions as type Transaction rather than String, or combine these two lists somehow to give me a big list to save to my txt file.

My transaction class is below

```
public class Transaction {
String details;
String date;

Double amount;



public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public Transaction(String details, double amount, String date) {
    super();
    this.details = details;
    this.date = date;
    
    this.amount = amount;
}
public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}
public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}
public Double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

}

Edit 1 - Added code for my transaction class

Comment: It's just for my use it's not going anywhere. I think I managed to brute force it by writing by changing the way it was written to a file so it was separated by a comma. When I read it into the list I looped over the list and split each input by a comma. Next I created a transaction object and just added each part of the original string to the object I just created. It didn't feel very elegant but it's done the job.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your List of Transaction to JSON Array as: (follow below link)

[Convert a list of string into json format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865584/convert-a-list-of-string-into-json-format)

Then, when you want to create a new transaction, you can read the whole file as an JSON array and get your Transaction objects from it as well. You will need to loop over the JSON array to get your Transaction objects. (To get Transaction objects, you will have to use ObjectMapper).

See this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109531/json-array-to-pojo#:~:text=Cliente%5B%5D%20clientes%3D%20mapper.,JSON%20and%20in%20the%20POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109531/json-array-to-pojo#:%7E:text=Cliente%5B%5D%20clientes%3D%20mapper.,JSON%20and%20in%20the%20POJO).

Comment: I'll have a little read up on JSON I've never used it before. Should I do this before I even add them to my list of transactions or once I have the full list the convert it?

Comment: Once you have the full list of your Transaction objects, you can then follow the link to get a JSON array. Follow the first link, it will help a lot to do that. Once you have your JSON array, print it and see how elegant it looks rather than keeping your individual Transaction Objects as (Type Date Amount) format. Other way around, you can read the file into a JSON array of JSON objects and looping on JSON array, you can convert JSON objects individually back to your previous saved Transaction objects. Hope, that serves your purpose. Happy coding. I have pasted both the link for your help.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a go now. One other question following on now is that am I able to write this new JSON array to a txt file the same way as a normal list?

Comment: Follow this one. Exactly what you need to write your JSON Array to a file:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-create-and-write-JSON-array-to-a-file-in-java

Comment: I'm getting an error "Json cannot be resolved". Do I need to add a dependency to my project and if so do you know what one?